# Does the stack penalty only count on the same item?

Tags: eve-online

Will using a thermal hardener and a kinetic hardener at the same time cause one of them to be penalized?

What if I use a thermal hardener, thermal resistance plating, and thermal energized plating?

How is the penalty calculated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stacking penalty applies to the bonus, not to the module.

If you have a [thermal hardener](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Armor_Thermic_Hardener_II) and an [EM hardener](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Armor_EM_Hardener_II) fitted, both would provide the full resist bonus. If you add [omni-resist plating](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Energized_Adaptive_Nano_Membrane_II), its thermal and EM bonuses would be reduced because of the stacking penalty, but its explosive and kinetic bonuses would not.

[The precise formula](http://wiki.eve-id.net/Stacking) is somewhat complicated, but it can be summarized as:

1. The first module provides 100% of its bonus.
2. The second provides ~87% of its bonus.
3. The third provides ~57% of its bonus.
4. The fourth provides ~28% of its bonus.
5. The fifth ensures your fit gets posted in a "[fail fits](http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&q=fail%20fits%20eve%20online)" thread on the forums.

The order you fit the modules doesn't matter; the one with the largest bonus will always be considered "first".

[Some modules](http://www.eve-wiki.net/index.php?title=Stacking_Penalty#Exceptions) (notably [Damage Control Units](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Damage_Control_II)) are exempt from stacking penalties.

Comment: how does eve decide which module gets penalised? if i have an all res and a single, having the penalty on the single would be harder then the all resistance. is it fitting order or?

Comment: @Andy: I updated the answer with more details.

Comment: +1. Thanks for also pointing me to exceptions. This explains yet another reason to not make a fit w/o DC (besides the obvious benefits of them). Prior to this I actually planned without them thinking I was losing out in some areas.